# Magento2 Full Page Cache not getting ENABLED by system

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, magento-fpc

We are in the last stages of a new port to Magento 2.4.5-p3 and I am having difficulty with the Full Page Cache.

Full Page Cache is enabled with Varnish Cache.  We had TTL set to 86400.  It is now set to 604800.
We run a process to warm the cache every night, going through all the sitemap (wfpc)

On the System->Cache Management page of the admin, the Page Cache shows  “INVALIDATED” (as does the Configuration Cache.)  It never gets set to ENABLED.  I understood (perhaps incorrectly) that if the TTL is 86400 that Magento would refresh the cache automatically every 24 hours.  This never happens.

Do we have to do something to get it to refresh, or do we have to do this manually of via a cron task?

Thanks